# Return on clicked element when the page back to previous

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a page with table consist hundreds of rows. Each row is a link which is opened a new page.

Is it possible if I'm browsing the table and click on some link which is somewhere on the bottom or middle of the table when I hit back button on the browser to redirect me back to that link which is clicked?

Generally I know how I can make `onClick` event on the button but I'm not sure that this is what I need

```
<input action="action" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" type="button" value="Back" />
```

The table is simple one

```
<table class="stripe">
<tr class="TableEvenLines">
    <td id="letter-a">
        <a href="example.php?id=1">Link 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="example.php?id=2">Link 2</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: window.history.back() ?

Comment: @Roy, that's seems to work. What is the difference between those two? They are both using window.history yet perform differently?

Comment: And I just need to add `<a href="example.php?id=1" onclick="window.history.back()">` to all href's, right?

Comment: _back to the link which is clicked_ - you want to go to the same page that is clicked.

Comment: @Saral, to the page and link that is clicked. Because as I said in the question the table is with many rows which means the page is scrollable. So, currently when the user open the link and click back button is going to the previous page but at the top of the table and must scroll bottom again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between window.history.go(-1) & window.history.back() is back() only goes back 1 page but go() goes back/forward the number of pages you pass as a parameter, relative to your current page.

Comment: I just found out that this solution is working only on latest version of Chrome Browser. Is there another solution which should work on all browsers

Comment: @Ivanov It should work on all versions....which version of the chrome had you tested??

Comment: just saw the reply. It is working on `Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106`. Doesn't work on any other browser. Tried on latests IE, Mozilla, Opera.